# How to Ignore characters in SELECT statement Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table

```
  KCode    T_Name     Description            

    A1001    name1            ssdad         
    K1002    name2            gfd          
    M1003    name3            gfdsffsdf    
    10A02     name2            gfd          
    1005     name5            fsfds        
    R1006    name6            dsgfgd      
    1005     name5            fsfds
```

I wanted to remove any characters that present in first occurance eg: A in A1001,not in 10A02  from KCode and that becomes **EID**. To be like

```
   KCode    T_Name     Description          EID  

    A1001    name1            ssdad        1001
    K1002    name2            gfd          1002
    M1003    name3            gfdsffsdf    1003
    10A02     name2            gfd         10A02
    1005     name5            fsfds        1005
    R1006    name6            dsgfgd       1006
    1005     name5           fsfds         1005
```

How do i specify that in a query?

Comment: Are you skipping the first character altogether, or just skipping the first character if it is a letter?

Comment: just skipping the first character if it is a letter

Comment: whats the possibility of first couple of characters being alphabet?

Comment: The table i mentioned is sample. I have mare than 300 rows. I can't tell the posibility of having couple of characters being alphabet

Comment: so you can have a `KCode` with value `AN102`?

Comment: NO, will have only one letter. Like A1002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments I think that the following sql statement should suffice :

```
Select  [KCode], [T_Name], [Description], 
    IIf(IsNumeric(Left([KCode],1)),[KCode], Mid([KCode],2)) As [EID] 
From [TableName]
```

Given that you just need to check if KCode starts with any non-numeric character.

**Edit : further request in comments**

```
Select  [KCode], [T_Name], [Description], 
    IIf([KCode] Like "*#*",        
    IIf(IsNumeric(Left([KCode],1)),[KCode], Mid([KCode],2)),
    "") As [EID] 
From [TableName]
```

Comment: I have 4 rows contains only Letters in **KCode**, i wanted to ignore them. how to specify them not to include in **IFF**

Comment: You want to ignore the complete row or ignore in calculating the EID?

Comment: ignore in calculating the EID

Comment: But those 4 values are showing as null in **EID**. Because you specified **""** thats why. I do need to display those 4 values as it is in calculating **EID**. I appreciate your help.